# Use two different completions in tcsh

Tags: tab-completion, tcsh

I want to make a tcsh completion that completes with both a relative directory (ie `p/*/d/`), or the output of a command (ie `p/*/'completionterms'/`). Is this possible? Looking at the tcsh man page it's not obvious.

And before anyone says use bash, I need to support both (bash was easy ;-).

For example, say I have this directory tree:

```
|-- dirone
|   `-- subdir
`-- dirtwo
```

And `completionterms` prints out:

```
desiredout outputone outputtwo
```

What I'm after is a completion such that both of these would get added. Thus:

```
$ commandtocomplete <tab>
dirone/ dirtwo/ desiredout outputone outputtwo
$ commandtocomplete d<tab>
dirone/ dirtwo/ desiredout
$ commandtocomplete dirone/s<tab>
$ commandtocomplete dirone/subdir
```

Comment: I don’t understand the question.  Can you please try to explain in a little more detail what you want to do (and what you want the system to do)?

Comment: @Scott: I've edited the question to include an example of what I'm after, hopefully it helps.